# Dropdown Select: Displaying category names with items

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am populating a dropdown select from my database. The dropdown select that I have managed to create so far contains some names of products only. I want to display the category names along with the products, but the category names should not be selectable.

I have following two tables.

Table Name: product_category

```
category_id     category_name
    1              Beverage
    2              Food
```

Table Name: products

```
product_id   category_id    product_name
    1           1              Pepsi
    2           2              Burger
```

My Model

```
 function products() {

     $this->db->select('product_name, product_id');
      $records=$this->db->get('products');

        $data=array();
        $data[''] = 'Select'; 
            foreach ($records->result() as $row)
                {
                    $data[$row->product_id] = $row->product_name;
                }

            return ($data);
        }
```

At present when I run my view file and click on the dropdown select, I get the values like following:

```
    Pepsi
    Burger
```

But what should I write more in my model above to make the dropdrown in my view file look like following?

**Beverage**

```
     Pepsi
```

**Food**

```
     Burger
```

Thanks :)
Just for your information I am using Codeigniter :0

Comment: Did you include the category in your query? i think you should include it to grab the category of product.

Comment: oK, but what should I write inside `foreach ($records->result() as $row)
                {
                    $data[$row->product_id] = $row->product_name;
                }
`

Comment: your query should be somethign like this:                              'select * from product INNER JOIN category ON product.category_id = category.category_id' so that you can get the name of your category..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I know what my query should be :) I just don't know what to write inside the foreach statement to display the category names. thanks :)

Comment: if your using the query that i have.. just try this              $data[$row->category_name] inside your foreach.. Uhhm.. Just give it a  try.. i'm not so familiar with CI :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeIgniter is so awesome, so in your case to achieve your example you can do a:

```
$arr = array( 'Beverage' => array( '1' => 'Pepsi' ),
              'Food' => array( '2' => 'Bruger' ));

echo dropdown('food_id', $arr);
```

So you will have an additional depth for each value where the first key is the name of the optgroup and 2nd is the id. It will have the structue `select > optgroup > option` as given in @Pitchinnate's reply

In your foreach, it would look like this:

```
$data[$row->category_name][$row->product_id] = $row->product_name;
```

Answer (score 2):

There is something for that called [optgroup](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp)

```
<select>
  <optgroup label='category 1'>
    <option value='1'>Item 1</option>
    <option value='2'>Item 2</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label='category 2'>
    <option value='3'>Item 3</option>
    <option value='4'>Item 4</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```